# Problems with default recipe chef passenger-apache

Tags: ruby, passenger, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am having problems with the default behavior of the passenger_apache2 cookbook. When I run 

`include_recipe "passenger_apache2::source"
include_recipe "passenger_apache2::mod_rails"`

I get an error about problems with the chef ruby path. I don't know if this is affected by the rbenv path (installed with riot's cookbook). Oddly enough, if I rerun the converge with test-kitchen, the error does not show up.

`````
Mxlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed  
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module _4.0.14_ --auto ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module (LoadError)
---- End output of /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module _4.0.14_ --auto ----
Ran /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module _4.0.14_ --auto returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/kitchen/cookbooks/passenger_apache2/recipes/source.rb

 50: execute "passenger_module" do
  51:   command "#{node['passenger']['ruby_bin']} #{node['passenger']['root_path']}/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module _#{node['passenger']['version']}_ -````-auto"
   52:   creates node['passenger']['module_path']
end
`````

Comment: I started looking in to this more, and I think my problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231281/rvm-nginx-passenger-in-chef. The user mentions that the path for ruby is picked up on the second run, as mine is.

When I log in to the server, I can see that rbenv is properly set in my $PATH, but chef does not seem to know about it until the second run.